# Power cycle on reboot?

Tags: boot, power, reboot

I have two identical computers (same mobo, memory, and peripherals) both running Ubuntu 12.10. The only difference is one has an Intel Core i7-3770K and the other has an Intel Core i7-3770S. I have also double checked that both computers have the exact same bios settings (minus cpu voltage levels).

**Here is the problem:** On reboot (via the OS or by pressing "reset" button), the computer with the 3770K does a full power cycle before booting up again. The computer with the 3770S stays powered on during reboot.

I desire to have both computers perform a full power cycle on reboot.

*My Questions*: 1) What causes a computer to power cycle / not power cycle during reboot. 2) What could potentially be the difference between my two set-ups that causes this?

Things I have tried:

1. Switching HDs between the computers does not produce different results. The behavior seems to follow the CPU/mobo hardware around, not the OS.

Comment: My guess would be it's in your power supply. Swap them out and see if it follows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be curious as to your CPU settings in the BIOS. I had a high-end Asus motherboard which would soft-reboot without a full power cycle using the stock CPU speeds. However, if you  enabled overclocking and overclocked the CPU, then it would always do a full power cycle when restarting (I presumed it was a safety precaution).